# UPS turning on and off repeatedly

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, ups

I'm using an Intex Protector UPS. When I push the power button it starts with a beep, which is normal, I know. But when the beep ends, the light which shows power turns off and button remains pressed. After  1-2 seconds, it beeps again. This keeps repeating every few seconds.

I thought it may be because it needs to be charged, so I left my ups with AC 220V for 9 hours. That did not help; it still keeps beeping. What might be the cause of this issue?

FWIW, I always push button to turn on UPS but the problem is I'm observing it from today. It was fine yesterday. I bought my UPS just 3-4 months before.

Comment: Yah! I always push button to turn on UPS but the problem is I'm observing it from today. It was fine yesterday. I bought my UPS just 3-4 months before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> “FWIW, I always push button to turn on UPS but the problem is I'm observing it from today. It was fine yesterday. I bought my UPS just 3-4 months before.”

Okay, this is your problem. And I can confirm personally because I used to do this myself all the time with APC UPS devices at home. You simply cannot turn UPS devices of any kind on and off daily as if you are turning a basic electrical device on and off daily.

The act of turning it on and off each day will actually wear out the UPS quicker than just leaving in on. When you turn it off each night (I assume) the battery in the UPS slowly drains itself. Then you turn it on again in the morning the next day and it has to refill the battery again. Forcing this type of battery to go through cycles like this definitely will wear the battery down as time goes on.

But you also say:

> “I bought my UPS just 3-4 months before.”

Okay, but this is definitely weird. In general what I describe about power cycling above relates to a UPS battery being worn down like this over a year or so.

If the battery died after just 3 to 4 months from the usage you described, then I would—as a guess—say that the battery if it were left on would have lasted about 9 to 12 months.

Sounds to me like the battery itself is defective or just is not “new” as sold to you.

If possible I would see about returning the whole unit to the manufacturer or get them to send you an RMA replacement for the battery.

But in general you have a defective unit and the daily powering on and off doesn’t help.

Answer (score 3):

First, check the user manual for the *beep* code. If you've lost the original, [look online (this link is for a German manual, but all I found in a brief search)](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1098593/Intex-Kom0229.html) .

Second, on many brands of UPS, repeated beeps indicate overload and/or weak battery. Test the UPS with **no** load (everything unplugged), and then gradually increase the load (it might be easiest to test using incandescent lamps). If the supply stops beeping when running without load, but beeping starts with a 25 or 40 watt (W) lamp, the battery is almost dead. If the beeping doesn't start until 200 W or more load, the supply is being overloaded by your PC and peripherals. Peripherals such as printers that are not needed for emergency use should be plugged into the mains before the UPS.

Comment: I didn't have printers connected to my ups. Only CPU and Monitor is connected.

Comment: How I can test load by increasing it. Is any device available for it.?

Comment: I tried something.First I connected only cpu. It was working properly. Then my monitor. The also it was working. But when I connected both. It is beeping.

Comment: What it mean? Over load? What should I do? It was working fine for last few months.

Comment: Replace battery or get another UPS.

Comment: I bought it just 3-4 months before

Comment: Then return it... perhaps it sat on the shelf so long that the battery was permanently damaged through complete discharge.